# what does "@" refer to in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that was provided to me to implement a business flow.
I see a formula in a column as below:
=[@[Inventory]]

I understand that this copies data from other column with heading 'Inventory'. But when I try to mimic this on a different sheet for a different column , I don't get any values. I'm I missing something here.

Comment: The formula you used as an example must be used within the same table as the Inventory column.

Answer (score 1):

The `=[@[Inventory]]` works only on columns, which are part of Excel Tables, created either from the Ribbon, through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or through [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)):

[image]

Comment: Or with Ctrl + T

Comment: @QHarr - true. This shortcut is working in Germany as well :D

Comment: Just wondering, but is `Table` the right name? I mean, I thought the proper name would be `ListObject`, but to be honest, in the spanish version of Excel this object is called `Table` too. So I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - I guess that `ListObject` is the class name in VBA. In the Excel front end it is known as `Table`. `TableObject` is a bit different , concerning pivot tables - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/tableobject-object-excel

Comment: Good to know, because I always used *Table* until I joined SO and then saw a lot of people called them *ListObject* , so I felt like I had been wrong my whole life LoL ;). To be honest, *Table* sounds good for me.

Comment: I think Table is the better word used here to avoid confusion. Similarly, technically the `@`  does not reference a Table Column but a `ListColumn` instead, but it is interchangable in its meaning and it's clear we're talking about the same thing

Comment: =SUM(DeptSales[[#Totals],[Sales Amount]],DeptSales[[#Data],[Commission Amount]]), now what could #Totals and #Data probably refer to ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a function of structure reference.

`@` means `ThisRow`.

You could learn more from:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: I checked your article as well,in this  =SUM(DeptSales[[#Totals],[Sales Amount]],DeptSales[[#Data],[Commission Amount]]), now what could #Totals and #Data probably refer to ?

Comment: From that article: "`[#Totals]` and `[#Data]` are special item specifiers that refer to specific portions of the table, such as the total row."

Answer (score 0):

This style of formula works with Excel listobject tables. The `@` symbol refers to the current row of the specified column. There's a good intro guide [here](http://www.databison.com/table-formulas-in-excel/)